# Check if the current request is already in request queue using restkit iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am using restkit for sending request, response mapping and all. but sometimes, i am sending same request multiple time which comes from different screens. So it get added to request queue. But i don't want to add request into request queue if the request is already there. How can i check that.

I am calling function like this

//Here I need to check if the following url is in RKRequestQueue. If it not there then call the below method,

```
[self getDataFromServer];


- (void)getDataFromServer{
    RKObjectManager *manager = [[RestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];

        [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/getData" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
            [RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
            loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
            loader.params = inputData;
            loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
     };

            loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
    };
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I was pretty sure that you can actually check the URLs of your requests in the RKRequestQueue, but I wasn't able to find anything useful for that in the [RKRequestQueue reference](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/Classes/RKRequestQueue.html). Instead, I've found the [containsRequest:](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/Classes/RKRequestQueue.html#//api/name/containsRequest%3a) method, but this will only compare RKRequest objects, not the actual URLs.

I guess the simplest thing to do is to create some kind of proxy for managing your network activity, implement the [requestQueue:didSendRequest:](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/Protocols/RKRequestQueueDelegate.html#//api/name/requestQueue%3adidSendRequest%3a) delegate method and monitor which URLs are currently processed.